# Is there an animatable transition-property for css filters?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm trying to animate CSS filters but can't find any information on the correct transition properties. What are they?

Here's an example: http://jsbin.com/onijim/3/

Comment: It should be the same property name, no? Make sure you're matching the prefixes properly as well.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
-webkit-transition : -webkit-filter 500ms linear
```

works in webkit. I don't know about filter support in FF or Opera.

I'm not sure I wholly understand your question.

Comment: You understood it correctly. Apparently the transition-property only works with prefixes as of this writing, thank you.

Comment: If I transition -webkit-filter, it animates fine, but after the animation the DIV appears empty. I'm just applying a blur of 5px to the div.

Comment: Apparently I'm getting a rendering glitch because it only breaks when the div containing the blur div has a left position set that is transitioned, but when the left is 0px the blur div no longer vanishes (or if I blur it, then change the left position of the container it still shows). Wish they would work out these kinks!

Comment: the blurred div also doesn't update while blurred if I make content changes via javascript or if the user clicks on a blurred button. After these changes are made, and I remove the blur then there are blur artifacts!

Answer (score 35):

That's what I'm using. For Mozilla the 2nd is working for me, but in my sources I found it with the -moz- prefix, so it doesn't hurt to keep both.

```
-webkit-transition: 1s -webkit-filter linear;
-moz-transition: 1s -moz-filter linear;
-moz-transition: 1s filter linear;
-ms-transition: 1s -ms-filter linear;
-o-transition: 1s -o-filter linear;
transition: 1s filter linear, 1s -webkit-filter linear;
```

Comment: As @AxeEffect mentionned in his comment, for latest Chrome support, you should add the `-webkit-filter` property to the unprefixed `transition`, like `transition: 1s filter linear, 1s -webkit-filter linear;`

Answer (score 6):

On last versions of Chrome which support `transition` without `-webkit-` prefix, if you are using `transition-property` (no shorthand `transition`) and properties like `filter` which still needs `-webkit-` prefix you need to mix unprefixed and prefixed code:

```
transition-property: width, left, transform, box-shadow, filter, -webkit-filter;
```

Note that the `filter` property is repeted with `-webkit-filter`. This is needed for browsers which do not use prefix, like Firefox, which in that case `-webkit-filter` is ignored.

Answer (score 5):

Check if you have different values in the filter properties:

WRONG

```
.link-image {
    transition: 0.3s;
    filter: brightness(80%);
}

.link-image:hover {
    transition: 0.3s;
    filter: brightness(10);
}
```

CORRECT

```
.link-image {
    transition: 0.3s;
    filter: brightness(80%);
}

.link-image:hover {
    transition: 0.3s;
    filter: brightness(100%);
}
```

Comment: In my case, filter transition didn't work when applying/removing a `grayscale(100%)` filter. Swapping between `grayscale(100%)` and `grayscale(0%)` worked.

Comment: This raises a really good point and should be higher voted, ensuring that your filter properties both before and after exist (even if the before value is `0%`) will animate the `filter` property accordingly