# transition into sepia in css

Tags: html, css, transition

i have these pieces of separate css code:

```
#social img:hover {
opacity:1; filter:alpha(opacity=100);
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) sepia(100%);
   -moz-filter: grayscale(100%) sepia(100%);
     -o-filter: grayscale(100%) sepia(100%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(100%) sepia(100%);
        filter: grayscale(100%) sepia(100%); 
}
```

and this one:

```
#social{color: #000; transition: color 1s ease;}
```

I want to make the first one similar to the second one so it actually make a **smooth transition from the original image** (#social) **into sepia tone**. How can I (sort of) merge these two pieces of code together? is it even possible in css without js?

example here:[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tucado/vZ2qA/1/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194115/is-there-an-animatable-transition-property-for-css-filters This should work.

Comment: @NickR Nope, with this code only grayscale is animated, not the sepia. See: http://jsfiddle.net/vZ2qA/5/ -- sepia alone does animate though: http://jsfiddle.net/vZ2qA/4/ -- i don't know why you would want *both* grayscale and sepia though...

Answer (score 2):

Really late response but it may help someone in need.
sepia, hue-rotate and probably other filter effects doesn't transition, so you can patch it adding a grayscale(0.1%) and it will animate the whole filter effect.

```css
img.greyscale {
  filter: grey;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0.1%) sepia(100%) hue-rotate(210deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
img.greyscale:hover {
  filter: none;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

```html
<img class="greyscale" src="https://mdebranding.files.wordpress.com/2015/01/marilyn-monroe-marilyn-monroe-35587386-500-505.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is all I can do in CSS. works on chrome. Unfortunately doesn't work in safari and firefox.
[jsfiddle.net/tucado/vZ2qA/10/](http://jsfiddle.net/tucado/vZ2qA/10/)

```
#social img:hover {

  -webkit-filter: sepia(100%);
     -moz-filter: sepia(100%);
       -o-filter: sepia(100%);
      -ms-filter: sepia(100%);
          filter: sepia(100%);

  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
     -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
           -o-filter: all 0.5s;    
          -ms-filter: all 0.5s;    
          transition: all 0.5s; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just set the transition property as you would with anything else:

**CSS:**

```
#social {
    transition: filter 1s ease;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/vZ2qA/6/

This code obviously doesn't include vendor prefixes.

Comment: In chrome it seems to only transition the grayscale and not the sepia http://jsfiddle.net/vZ2qA/3/ (firefox and IE doesn't appear to do anything at all). WIth ONLY sepia defined in filters, it is animated, however http://jsfiddle.net/vZ2qA/4/

Comment: It seems to work if you reverse the properties so sepia is before grayscale: http://jsfiddle.net/vZ2qA/6/

Comment: It doesn't look like sepia is applied at all there?

Comment: You're right, this is very strange.  It's probably a Chrome (which I assume you're using) bug.  Either way the code _should_ work.

Comment: Yeah the filter only appears to work in Chrome at all.